# SQL Anywhere 11 - Loop to TRUNCATE specific tables?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to figure out how to create a looped truncate to truncate (or delete) the data in specific tables only. There are something like 30 or so tables that need to be truncated, and I want to avoid just using a list of truncate statements. I can't seem to find any good examples of doing this, and no matter what I try, I get a "right truncated" error.

Example 1:

```
FOR anlyc_tables AS curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table_name FROM systable WHERE table_name LIKE 'table_to_truncate_prefix%'
    DO EXECUTE (
        'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + table_name
    );
END FOR;
```

This one throws no errors, but completes in .078 seconds and doesn't actually truncate anything.

Example 2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE truncate_analytics()

BEGIN
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR;
DECLARE curs DYNAMIC SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM systable WHERE table_name LIKE 't_anlyc%';

OPEN curs WITH HOLD;
FETCH NEXT curs INTO @table_name;

WHILE(sqlstate = 0) LOOP
    FETCH NEXT curs INTO @table_name;
    TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
END LOOP;
END
GO

CALL truncate_analytics()
GO
```

Results in the "right truncated" error and the tables are not truncated.

I think I'm missing something really obvious here, but I don't have a ton of experience with SQL scripting in this manner, and can't seem to find any working examples of this to prove it's even possible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a few things at work that are preventing the code from working.

With your second example, the text "TRUNCATE TABLE table_name" is going to look for a table named table_name. table_name won't be treated for it's variable value, but will be considered a object identifier. FWIW, I'm not sure how this would cause a right truncation error.

Depending on what you consider the prefix for a table, you might not be getting the list of tables you expect. If you are considering the user to be the prefix (i.e. dba.my_table), your select isn't going to grab the necessary tables; there can be multiple tables with the same name, just different owners. If you want to select based on user, you'll need to join to the SYSUSER view.

Lastly, using a cursor for this can be done. It would require WITH HOLD as you already have, because the TRUNCATE TABLE statement issues an implicit commit and closes cursors otherwise. (Note that WITH HOLD requires explicit closing of the cursor, otherwise it will remain open until connection close.) Another option is to build a string of statements to execute, and use the execute or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on them as a batch.

Hope This Helps,
Tyson